# Discard some dictionary items in list during random.choice

Tags: python, random

I want to get random item from a list, also I don't want some items to be consider while `random.choice()`. Below is my data structure

```
x=[
  { 'id': 1, 'version':0.1, 'ready': True  }
  { 'id': 6, 'version':0.2, 'ready': True }
  { 'id': 4, 'version':0.1, 'ready': False }
  { 'id': 35, 'version':0.1, 'ready': False  }
  { 'id': 45, 'version':0.1, 'ready': False  }
  { 'id': 63, 'version':0.1, 'ready': True   }
  { 'id': 34, 'version':0.1, 'ready': True   }
  { 'id': 33, 'version':0.1, 'ready': True   }
]
```

I can get the random item by using `random.choice(x)`. But is there any way, consider `'ready': True` attribute of item while `random.choice()`.

Or any SIMPLE trick to achieve this?

NOTE: I want to use python in-built modules to avoid dependencies like `numpy`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose from a list whose elements satisfy your criteria:

```
random.choice([elem for elem in x if elem["ready"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a *new* list with a list comprehension, selecting those items you want to randomly select from:

```
ready_items = [d for in x if d["ready"]]
random.choice(ready_items)
```

You can combine the two into one expression:

```
random.choice([d for in x if d["ready"]])
```

but if you are going to use `random.choice()` more than once then generating `ready_items` just once is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you want may be [`List Comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) .

First, filter the list to the final form you want `l = [e for e in x if e["ready"]]`

Second, use `random.choice` on it, `ret = random.choice(l)`